# Initializing signals in vhdl componets

Tags: vhdl

I was hoping you could help me with a problem I encountered while trying to design synchronous circuits.

I have a simple D flip-flop in my design, such as the one shown in the figure below. But when I initialize my inputs and set the `reset` to 1 in the test bench, the output of the D flip-flop is always undefined (as can be seen in the "Objects" view), even though I explicitly define it to be 0 when `reset` is high (the code for the D flip-flop is shown below).

This causes errors in larger circuits when I use the flip-flops and the outputs as signals to other components that require a defined input.  How can I achieve an output of zero when my `reset` is high during initialization?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Dff_en is
  port (
    d       : in std_logic;
    en      : in std_logic;
    clk     : in std_logic;
    reset   : in std_logic;
    q       : out std_logic
  ) ;
end entity;
architecture rtl of Dff_en is

    signal q_next, q_reg : std_logic;

begin
    --dff logic
    process(clk, reset) is
    begin 
        if(reset = '1') then
            q_reg <= '0';
        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
            q_reg <= q_next;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- next-state logic
    q_next <= d when (en = '1') else q_reg;

    --output
    q <= q_reg;

end architecture; -- arch
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You do not provide a testbench for others to recreate the problem.

Comment: Vhdl `'U'` value means uninitialised, not undefined. Vhdl `std_logic` does not provide an undefined value. The closest would be "unknown" which is defined as `'X'`

Comment: Did you let the simulator run at least a delta time? If your screenshot shows the moment at simulation start, `q` has to be `'U'`, of course. You might want to read the chapter on simulation in your simulator's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only update the `q_reg` output when there are events on the signals in the sensitivity list `(clk, reset)`.  VHDL (and Verilog) require events to trigger changes.  With signal initialization, then at time 0 the values are set, but there are no further events to simulate.

Even if you did a `run 100 ns`, there would be no change in outputs since you have not had any events.  Change either `clk` or `reset` some time after time 0 and try again.